# Media queries not working 'till i put !important

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, media-queries

my website use bootstrap 4 and a css file i made.

in the bottom of this css file, i put some media queries:

```
@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .address .contact {
    text-align: center;
  }
}

/* Small devices (tablets, 768px and up) */
@media (min-width: 768px) {

}

/* Medium devices (desktops, 992px and up) */
@media (min-width: 992px) {  }

/* Large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {  }

@media screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:992px){
  .left{
    margin-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .picto{
    width: 40%;
  }

}
```

And here is a part of code:

```
<section id="section_address" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                <div class="address">
                    <h5>ADDRESS</h5>
                    1 street,<br>
                    75000, PARIS
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
                <div class="contact">
                    <h5>MYCOMPANY</h5>
                    01 11 22 33 44<br>
                    contact@mycompany.com<br>
                    <a href="http://mycompany.com" target="_blank">http://mycompany.com</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

But my media queries are not working, except when i add `!important` to each line. But i can't do that for each line and i already use media queries and i never had to do that.

Comment: It might be possible that other files are affecting your styles. Such as the order in which it is included.

Comment: Did you try moving your style sheet to the bottom of the head tag (i.e. the last style sheet in the list)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap css file should be referenced before your custom css file in your html page. If not bootstrap css will Cascade or overwrite your rules.

Comment: Did you tried include your css after the bootstrap css? Can you be more elaborate on your issue?

Comment: yes, in my html file, the links to my css files are (in the order):
bootstrap, fontawesome, swiper and main.css my file containing media queries

Comment: What is the style which hasn't been applied. Is it .address . contact or .left or .picto?

Comment: all of these! .address, .contact, .left, .picto

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198840/discussion-between-xpd-and-alexking2005).

Comment: i answered you in the chat. Must i put the solution here? or the chat can be seen by everyone ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, avoid using `!important` unless you absolutely have to, it's a maintenance hazard.

Instead, look at how you could make your rules more specific than the bootstrap ones. Inspect the DOM and look at the problematic rules, then update your selectors with reference to the [specificity rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) so that they take precedence.

Regarding your newly-added code:

```
@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .address .contact {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

This selects for all `.contact` class elements as descendants of `.address' elements. This hierarchy isn't present in the pasted code.

If you want to select them both then you need a comma:

```
@media (max-width: 575px) {
    .address, .contact {
        text-align: center;
     }
}
```

If that isn't specific enough then this almost certainly will be:

```
@media (max-width: 575px) {
    #section_address .address, #section_address .contact {
        text-align: center;
     }
}
```

Other than that, I can't see `.left` or `.picto` anywhere.

Comment: I edited my question to had some code, the class used is 'unique' in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your custom CSS added after all other CSS. Because your custom CSS should be added after all other CSS files. whereby your custom CSS will override other CSS.

Because CSS applies "top to bottom".

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the elements to which you applied your own CSS classes also have Bootstrap classes applied to them (like `.row`, `column`, `col-12` and many others), and the Bootstrap CSS rules (especially those which combine several classes) have a higher *specifity*, which overrules your own classes.

To get the result you want, use the browser tools / inspector on those elements and look which CSS class / CSS rule / selector is applied. Then create a rule which uses the same selector (combination of classes) PLUS your own class, which will result in a higher specifity and therefore overrule the original Bootstrap rule.

Comment: i created a div under the div with the bootstrap classes.